# Proving bounded convergence for random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

In a homework exercise, we are given a sequence $X_1, X_2, ..$ of random variables, and a random variable $X$ on a probability space $( F, \Omega, \mathbb{P})$ such that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability. We are tasked to show that if $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \leq K) = 1$ for all $n\geq 1$ then we can conclude that $\mathbb{P}(|X| \leq K+1) =1$. I've tried to apply the definitions learned in class, but I cant start the argument. Im sure there is some technique I should apply here, but I cant figure it out.

Edit: convergence of $(X_n)$ in probability was defined as
$\mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: What does the definition of convergence in probability tell you? Can you relate the quantities you are given information about to $|X|$ using any inequalities you know?

Comment: The reverse triangle inequality may be helpful in transforming convergence in probability to the inequality you want. When posting questions like this, it's helpful to write out explicitly what definition you learned in class - sometimes there are multiple (equivalent) definitions of the same concept, and knowing exactly where you're at can be instructive in understanding why you're having trouble getting started.

Comment: I tried using the triangle inequality, but to no progress. And I fail to see how to use the reverse triangle inequality, using the markov inequality was a sometimes useful technique we learnedin class but i could not see it fit hete. I added Convergence in probability as it was defied in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to show that $\mathbb P\left(\lvert X\rvert >K+1\right)=0$. To this aim, we can use the inclusion,
$$
\left\{ \lvert X\rvert >K+1\right\}\subset \left\{ \lvert X_n\rvert >K\right\}\cup \left\{ \lvert X-X_n\rvert >1\right\}
$$
(to see this, look at the opposite inclusion of complements).

Then take probabilities, bound the probability of the union by the sum of probabilities and conclude.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this allowed me to produce a solution! Do you have any hint to now show how this now implies L1 convergence of $X_n \rightarrow X$? If i assume L1 convergence then I could prove that I have convergence in expectation and hence I am finished.

Comment: Could not edit my comment; I now need to use the assumption on boundedness in probability as given above to show L1 convergence, any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: In the OP, you did not mention expectations. Convergence in $L^1$ follows from an adaptation of the dominated convergence theorem. By adaptation, I mean the version of the dominated convergence theorem with convergence in probability.

Comment: The whole exercise starts with a) the OP  then, b) using the assumption of bddness, the next task is to show L1 convergence of $(X_n)$ to $X$, finally c) show that L1 convergence implies convergence in expectation. I could do part c) assuming b), and now I completed part a). I have to do part b), but I cant see how to show L1 convergence after solving the OP, any hint?

Comment: $E|X_n-X|\leqslant E[|X_n-X|1_{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon}]+\varepsilon\leqslant (2K+1)\mathbb P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$.